# r DT::datatable with formatStyle - apply nested css element 'hover'

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

Hello everyone You need to implement such a css construction via FormatStyle.

```css
nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

For some reason, this design does not work:

```r
formatStyle(
    'colname',
    # working
    cursor          = 'pointer',
    # not working
    hover           = list('text-decoration' = 'underline'))
```

Which one will work?

Comment: `hover` is not a CSS property

Answer (score 0):

Limitations of css itself. You need to declare a class to the column and write properties to this class in style.css.